# Is it valid to contract edges after condensing a graph to a dag?

Tags: graph-theory

Let's say this is my starting graph:

$$a \rightarrow b \Leftrightarrow c \rightarrow d $$

Where ($b\Leftrightarrow c$) implies that both ($b\leftarrow c$) and ($b\rightarrow c$) exist.

After condensation I have this dag:

$$ a \rightarrow bc \rightarrow d $$

At this point, I want to contract edges. Are any of these valid?

$$
abc \rightarrow d \\
a \rightarrow bcd \\
abcd
$$

Comment: Your question lacks a little bit of context/definition so it is difficult for me to understand completely your question. However, when condensing $b\iff c$ into a single vertex $bc$, you do not lose information, whereas if $a\to bc$ becomes $abc$ (or any other operations you mentionned), I would understand that $a\iff b \iff c$ given the previous condensation. So you would lose information (the fact that only $a\to bc$ and not $bc\to a$).

Comment: That is helpful, thanks. The "lose information" part gives me a better intuition for this kind of thing.

Comment: You should consider whether it is important or not in your problem to lose information : if it's not, then your condensing/contracting operations would be valid.

Comment: My problem is related to graph embedding - I want to encode the shape of the graph in a lower-dimensional space. As a pre-filtering step, I want to remove "superfluous" nodes/edges so I'm left with the "essential" graph shape, but the problem is I don't know of an algorithm that can prune everything except the "essential" nodes.

Comment: Okay. I'm not an expert of the field, but maybe the keyword "graph coarsening" is what you are looking for. There is this excellent paper you might look at: http://proceedings.mlr.press/v108/jin20a/jin20a.pdf

Comment: That's one of the papers in my reading list! Along with [harp](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.07845).